# JQUERY Auto hide a SELECT LIST if it contains a specific value

Tags: jquery

```
<select name="productsize" id="productsize">
    <option value="">1</option>
    <option value="">xxx</option>
</select>
```

How with jQuery to Hide this SELECT list if it contains "xxx" as one of the options?

Is it possible?

### UPDATE:

The above is jast an example, ROB answered to it, and it really working. But in my situation this select list is generated first of all by another jquery function.

this is it:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function GetAvailProductSizes() {
    $('select#productsize option').remove();
    $('select#productsize').append('<option value=""><? echo $langdata['oneprodpage_selectsize']; ?>...</option>');

    var color = $('#productcolor').val();
    if (color > 0) {
        var availsizes;
        var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http_request.open( "GET", '<? echo ROOT; ?>/autocompleteavailsizes/?productid=<? echo $thisproduct['id']; ?>&color=' + color, true );
        http_request.send(null);
        http_request.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if ( http_request.readyState == 4 ) {
                if ( http_request.status == 200 ) {
                    availsizes = eval( "(" + http_request.responseText + ")" );
                    $('select#productsize').show();

                    for (var i = 0; i < availsizes.length; i++) {
                        $('select#productsize').append('<option value="' + availsizes[i].id + '">' + availsizes[i].name + '</option>');
                    };
                } else {
                    alert( "There was a problem with the URL." );
                }
                http_request = null;
            }
        };
    };
}
```

//-->

I tryied this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function GetAvailProductSizes() {
    $('select#productsize option').remove();
    $('select#productsize').append('<option value=""><? echo $langdata['oneprodpage_selectsize']; ?>...</option>');

    var color = $('#productcolor').val();
    if (color > 0) {
        var availsizes;
        var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http_request.open( "GET", '<? echo ROOT; ?>/autocompleteavailsizes/?productid=<? echo $thisproduct['id']; ?>&color=' + color, true );
        http_request.send(null);
        http_request.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if ( http_request.readyState == 4 ) {
                if ( http_request.status == 200 ) {
                    availsizes = eval( "(" + http_request.responseText + ")" );
                    $('select#productsize').show();
                    $('select#productsize option').each(function() {
                        if ($(this).text() == '-') {
                            $('select#productsize').hide();
                        }
                    });
                    for (var i = 0; i < availsizes.length; i++) {
                        $('select#productsize').append('<option value="' + availsizes[i].id + '">' + availsizes[i].name + '</option>');
                    };
                } else {
                    alert( "There was a problem with the URL." );
                }
                http_request = null;
            }
        };
    };
}
```

//-->

but its not working...

Oh yeah and my select list has style **display: none**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fairly straight forward...

```
$('#productsize option').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == 'xxx') {
        $('#productsize').hide();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uRAsu/

Comment: Your answer is Excelent!!! Thankyou! But now I understood that i placed a wrong question. I will update my question

Answer (score 2):

```
$('select:has(option:contains("xxx"))').hide();
```

Or:

```
$('#productsize option').filter(function(){
   var t = this.textContent || this.innerText;
   return t === 'xxx'; 
}).parent().hide();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Vz7gY/

Comment: @user1978483 Yes, read between the lines, the first one hides it and the second one shows it http://jsfiddle.net/GH87W/

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Rob's answer would be to check the number of elements selected from this selector.

```
if($('#productsize option[value="xxx"]').length) {
    $('#productsize').hide();
}
```

This assumes that you set the value attribute of each option rather than the inner text.

Comment: This would probably be the better solution if the options had values. In his case, the text is xxx, not the value.